# datetime не работает в while True

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, while

Суть программы такова: если end_date (конечное время) больше now_date (время, которое сейчас), то запускаем бесконечный цикл и ждем, пока now_date не станет >= end_date, если это произошло, то выполняем код в цикле...

Встала одна проблема: Когда запускаю бесконечный цикл и наступает то самое время, когда now_date >= end_date, программа ничего не делает и цикл продолжает висеть...

```
end_date = '2020-03-15 19:26'
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
now_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
now_date = datetime.datetime.now().strptime(now_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
while True:
    if now_date >= end_date:
        for file in file_names:
            if len(file_names) >= 0:
                print('Файл ' + file + ' успешно удалён!')
                try:
                    os.remove(DIR_PATH + '/' + file)
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    pass
```

Comment: 1 - Запустите под отладчиком, и посмотрите, выполняется ли условие. 2 - возможно условие выполняется, но список файлов пустой, проверьте это

Comment: список не пустой, отладчик не работает в моей системе

Comment: Какая конкретно система?

Comment: debian, а если точнее, то kali linux 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc'

Comment: Не вижу причин, почему на этой системе может не работать отладчик. Ну не работает отладчик - добавьте тестовый вывод.

Comment: отладчик починил, проблемы с пакетами были

Comment: Небольшой комментарий к коду: не нужны такие сложные манипуляции с `now_date`. можно просто записать `now_date = datetime.datetime.now()`, потом это значение сравнивать с `end_date`. `now_date` будет содержать дату и время с точностью до миллисекунд, но это никак не мешает сравнению.

Comment: Да, действительно! Запомню на будущее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте при каждом проходе цикла заново записывать текущее время в переменную now_date

Comment: Кстати да, если значение now_date внутри цикла не меняется, то и условие никогда не выполнится (если оно изначально не выполнялось)